# "Relation between link-tag and href" - What does that mean?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the meaning of the rel-attribute within the CSS link-tag.

One finds a lot of resources, which say something like e.g. "*rel is short for relation. It specifies the relation between the tag and href.*" But that doesn't help me much.

Because: **How is that meant?**

What's exactly is meant with "relation" within the specific case CSS link-tag?

Comment: There are different uses of the `link` tag, of which the loading of external CSS is the most common. The `rel` attribute tells the browser what sort of relationship is being loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Comment: @Mitya Ah, okay. It instructs the browser that it shall treat the external resource as a stylesheet. So to say.

Comment: Yes. It probably has some effect on SEO, too, though I can't be certain. It's just one of those attributes you include and don't think too much about (or perhaps that's just me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different uses of the `link` tag, of which the loading of external CSS is the most common.

The `rel` attribute tells the browser what sort of relationship is being loaded.

Read more: MDN docs